# I'm coding in colab using tensorflow. I'm encountered with this error. How do I proceed. I tried installing various versions of tf as well as tf.hub

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub, google-colaboratory

```
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE,
                                   input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,), 
                                   output_shape=[FV_SIZE])

Error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-4be659037f32> in <module>()
      1 feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE,
      2                                    input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,),
----> 3                                  output_shape=[FV_SIZE]
      4                                    )
```

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py in hash(self)

TypeError: Variable is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use your TensorFlow hub as latest like 0.10.0
it will solve this

```
!pip install 'tensorflow-hub == 0.10.0'
```